# Cross dissolve error in Permiere Pro

Tags: premiere, effects, transitions, multi-camera

I have a multicam project of 4 cameras. I did the multi-camera record which resulted in a single track sequence with the switching between the cameras. Then I applied the default transition to all cuts, which is the Cross Dissolve.

Although the right transition effect appeared everywhere, and in most cases it shows correctly, in some cases the effect works as if it was a Dip to Black (no, it's not coming from the footage). If I delete the auto-added Cross Dissolve transition and add it again manually, it works as expected. Is this a bug in Premiere?

Comment: Same thing with me. Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which version of PPro you are using; but in version CS6 and prior there IS a bug with cross dissolve which is a bit idiosyncratic.

The fix; move all of your video (select all) up one layer.

Then add black video; or a color matte (black) which is the length of your program to the bottom (first) video track.

This in essence resets all the preview files PPro has generated; (which I believe is where the problem is).

If this doesn't work; you could try changing the default transition from cross dissolve to film dissolve... the visual effect is not "identical" but I don't think it would be a deal breaker if my first suggestion doesn't work for you.

Last option; you can pull the clips in; and out; using Trim; and make sure you make sure the dissolve rests on a new different frame on the timeline. + or - 1 frame to the left or right.

But yes; I have seen this; and it's why all our editors now cut starting on layer 2; and the last step of the process; is we lay black under the entire program before output.

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same problem with the cross dissolve in a multicam track doing a Dip to Black in PPro CC 2017 April update. I saved my project, shut down PPro and restarted PPro, and that seemed to solve it for me.